# Is there anyway to move the card reveal action button to the bottom of the card in Materialize CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment, materialize, material-icons

Is there a way to move the button that reveals the card to be at the bottom of the card instead of off to the side? For example: Having it be where the link placeholder text is and still reveal the card upon click.

Or is it only stuck within a certain category?

How would I go about doing that in Materialize CSS?

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
  <img class="activator" src="images/office.jpg">
</div>
<div class="card-content">
  <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
  <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
</div>
<div class="card-reveal">
  <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
  <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
</div>
```